# Mootools submit form only works when selecting form through id

Tags: javascript, forms, mootools, submit

I've been trying to submit a form through mootools (1.4.5) on FF 14. The form does not contain an input named submit (which is often the problem). What I want is onchange in a select to submit the form. After half an hour the code below was my first attempt that got it working. objSelect is a select object that is contained within the form that I need to submit.

```js
$(''+objSelect.getParent('form').get('id')).submit();
```

.

**What the reason that the code below doesn't work as well?**

```js
// Without the explicit cast to string (''+); doesn't work
$(objSelect.getParent('form').get('id')).submit();
```

nor

```js
// Most obvious way; doesn't work
objSelect.getParent('form').submit();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't have child nodes with reserved names that get exported via old DOM level API - see here how forms are being represented: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/forms.html#access

So basically - at an element level, if you have:

- form

  - input[name=foo]
  - input[name=bar]

`form.foo` and `form.bar` will reference these element on the form element object.

the problem in your case is:

- form (with a `.submit` and `.reset` method)

  - button[name=submit]

now `form.submit` stops referencing the submit method and starts referencing the input element.

you still submit this form by doing either:

- rename the element that is wrong or remove from the form.
- cheat by calling submit from a clean form.

`new Element("form").submit.call(this.getParent("form"));`

basically you create a new form element with a clean submit method. that returns an object and you call the method with the other "dirty" form as context.

this is just the same as doing

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
```

Comment: Sorry, I do not fully understand.

Also, wouldn't this have been super easy with jQuery? I'm kind of stuck with Mootools, trying to make the best of it ;) Usually it is just different, but in instances like my example it gets frustrating.

Comment: that's the trouble with a lot of jquery users. no idea what is going on under the hood... i challenge you to show me how this is different in jquery - http://jsfiddle.net/wu89e/ - an element is an element, whatever your framework. this is a native form method.

Comment: and if you want to call the `.submit()` via the api, it also fails. http://jsfiddle.net/wu89e/1/ - and this working as suggested above: http://jsfiddle.net/wu89e/2/ - after the alert, the correct way to submit.

Comment: I misunderstood your answer. There is no element named submit in my form. So your answer I still don't understand...